# Change default color of text

Tags: color, default

Is it possible to change the default color of the text. I.e. what is usually black. I would like to have that text be a different color without having to use `\textcolor` everywhere

Comment: Just use `\color{some color}` at the beginning.

Comment: use \color in the preamble. This will set the default color.

Comment: Notice that there is a difference between  putting `\color{blue}` before or after the `\begin{document}`... Try for example to add a footnote!